# How can i render kinect depth/color stream image in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, kinect-sdk

I am beginner in kinect for windows development. I want to display depth stream or color stream without background like the one [here](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Your-Shape-Fitness-Evolved/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8025553084f), shown in red,purple color. is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Do you want to render the pure stream as a texture or do you want to render 3d objects?

Comment: I want to render a human body, without background as a texture.

Comment: You get the depth stream with the player index embedded in it. So for creating the texture you can iterate the pixels of the color stream, look up the according value in the depth stream. If the player index defines no player, write black to the texture. Otherwise write the color value to the texture (may be multiplied with a color for tinting).